# How to split a pandas column into intervals?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to split my dataframe into 5 intervals based on a numerical variable.

Ideally, I would like these intervals to be:  `x < 15000`, `x >= 15000 and x < 30000`,  `x >= 30000 and x < 45000`, `x < 45000`. (So, with nice round values)

To do so I have implemented the following code:

```
def convert_number(original_value):
    target_value = round(original_value, -3) + 5000
    return target_value

def FasciaImporto(df, col_name ='NUMERICAL_VARIABLE'):

    Fascia_importo = []

    
    intervals = pd.cut(df[col_name], bins=4, labels=['Interval 1', 'Interval 2', 'Interval 3', 'Interval 4'])
    df['INTERVAL'] = intervals

    intervals_ = [
                    '<' + str(convert_number(round(df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 1'][col_name].max()))), 
                    '[' + str(convert_number(round(df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 1'][col_name].max()))) + '-' + str(convert_number(round(df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 2'][col_name].max()))) + ']',
                    '[' + str(convert_number(round(df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 2'][col_name].max()))) + '-' + str(convert_number(round(df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 3'][col_name].min()))) + ']',
                    '[' + str(convert_number(round(df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 3'][col_name].max()))) + '-' + str(convert_number(round(df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 4'][col_name].min()))) + ']',
                    '>' + str(convert_number(round(df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 4'][col_name].min())))
    ]
    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        val = df[col_name].iloc[i]
        if val < df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 1'][col_name].max():
            Fascia_importo.append(intervals_[0])
        elif val > df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 1'][col_name].max() and val < df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 2'][col_name].max():
            Fascia_importo.append(intervals_[1])
        elif val > df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 2'][col_name].max() and val < df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 3'][col_name].max():
            Fascia_importo.append(intervals_[2])
        elif val > df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 3'][col_name].max() and val < df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 4'][col_name].max():
            Fascia_importo.append(intervals_[3])
        else:
            Fascia_importo.append(intervals_[4])


    df['FASCIA_IMPORTO'] = Fascia_importo
    print(df['FASCIA_IMPORTO'].value_counts())
```

I am applying this function to different dataframes and it works more ore less.
HOWEVER, in one case the interval 3 is empty so when I run

```
val > df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 2'][col_name].max() and val < df[df['INTERVAL'] =='Interval 3'][col_name].max()
```

my code breaks.

How can I improve my code to avoid errors and to have nicer intervals?

Sample

```
[18511.18,
 82000.0,
 16313.97,
 24771.96,
 10930.93,
 22163.14,
 16586.07,
 15766.2,
 2953.53,
 912.1,
 531.77,
 6509.83,
 8634.2,
 10181.41,
 1495.26,
 6555.12,
 10523.55,
 22200.0,
 20230.0,
 18400.0,
 17999.56,
 15807.29,
 4794.6,
 3679.48,
 5667.89,
 5296.92,
 4848.96,
 5997.53,
 3286.98,
 13258.53,
 15400.0,
 10614.2,
 12235.0,
 2953.35,
 9699.54,
 14880.0,
 6295.46,
 10170.0,
 6824.8,
 4177.87,
 3005.95,
 15186.45,
 7649.42,
 2432.2,
 3081.8,
 9065.42,
 6033.63,
 658.68,
 12310.0,
 650.73,
 2767.09,
 9770.0,
 6246.9,
 2175.46,
 2381.98,
 12460.0,
 1957.37,
 2613.85,
 2407.9,
 4744.32,
 4415.23,
 2143.3,
 1141.28,
 2000.38,
 1676.95,
 1377.39,
 54.08,
 6864.97,
 81.56,
 96.68,
 7583.0,
 408.29,
 1735.16,
 272.49,
 157.79,
 689.56,
 3586.12,
 241.66,
 103.98,
 5620.0,
 411.42,
 387.96,
 815.18,
 536.82,
 3019.5,
 160.92,
 315.58,
 256.23,
 7063.96,
 10200.0,
 244.01,
 6199.32,
 936.79,
 5838.78,
 8070.0,
 8760.7,
 4334.65,
 2646.84,
 900.38,
 5197.19,
 5450.15,
 5447.3,
 4961.8,
 2266.28,
 1675.23,
 6029.51,
 2066.14,
 4616.34,
 1437.3,
 4819.49,
 4470.0,
 1860.66,
 4040.11,
 1502.95,
 467.3,
 251.98,
 3200.53,
 1499.83,
 459.38,
 4862.74,
 2171.43,
 1237.1,
 2067.19,
 1202.94,
 3830.47,
 4228.93,
 6100.0,
 1229.15,
 3513.0,
 3050.0,
 3910.0,
 510.05,
 5201.09,
 962.85,
 603.92,
 1237.42,
 63.72,
 2613.54,
 319.45,
 5415.0,
 1425.98,
 5518.09,
 3646.13,
 2269.72,
 2804.19,
 1747.12,
 2646.87,
 284.56,
 2135.46,
 3602.5,
 4965.06,
 508.76,
 141.52,
 214.94,
 4320.0,
 259.0,
 295.75,
 4955.0,
 1379.58,
 3730.45,
 6000.0,
 523.05,
 1310.22,
 842.35,
 3319.75,
 2674.75,
 141.2,
 1877.21,
 389.7,
 5547.56,
 1030.0,
 1206.64,
 135.52,
 1770.2,
 4840.0,
 687.53,
 3412.44,
 2972.23,
 864.67,
 3735.4,
 1135.16,
 669.1,
 501.3,
 160.23,
 200.19,
 1015.28,
 1100.0,
 244.32,
 496.95,
 3209.62,
 1920.15,
 1815.75,
 2611.77,
 2176.35,
 1683.95,
 4945.8,
 781.36,
 4005.25,
 553.72,
 514.29]
```

Comment: As I said, I would like this to work with any dataset.

Comment: I've added a sample of data, as a list. You should create a df from there and then give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"some_value":[1, 44746, 27637, 18236, 1000, 15000,34000]}
)
```

You can use `pd.cut` to specify how a column should be split into intervals, by specifying the bins. This can be an integer, in which case the data will be split into that many bins of equal width. Or you can use a sequence of values in which case those will be used as your interval boundaries.

With the right parameter you can specify if the right most value must be included in your interval or if it should be the first value of the next interval.

With the label parameter you can define custom labels for your intervals.

Assigning the result of pd.cut to our dataframe will give us this result.

```
df.assign(
cutoffs=pd.cut(
    df.some_value,
    [0, 15000, 30000, 45000],
    right=False,
    labels=["x < 15000", "x >= 15000 and x < 30000", "x >= 30000 and x < 45000"],
)
```

|  | some_value | cutoffs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | x < 15000 |
| 1 | 44746 | x >= 30000 and x < 45000 |
| 2 | 27637 | x >= 15000 and x < 30000 |
| 3 | 18236 | x >= 15000 and x < 30000 |
| 4 | 1000 | x < 15000 |
| 5 | 15000 | x >= 15000 and x < 30000 |
| 6 | 34000 | x >= 30000 and x < 45000 |